# How to replace the NA in a dataset using the mean of the cluster groups

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, missing-data, imputation

I'm doing a project for an university exam and I'm analyzing a dataset of the UN I took from Kaggle.
The problem of this dataset is that there are a lot of missing values and our teacher suggested to do 2 differents analysis, one imputing mean of the variables and one imputing median.

Instead of computing the overall means of the variables I wanted to impute the mean of the 4 groups that were created using a cluster analysis.

I succeeded in creating the 4 groups and seeing the summary of the variables inside the 4 groups, now I need to impute the means only in the NA observation for each country. Some countries don't have NA at all.
I thought of using a loop, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data frame with a dependent variable `y` (with some missing cases) and a grouping variable `x`, then you can create a new column with the means of the non-missing cases using `ave`:

```
df$mean_y <- ave( df$y , df$x , FUN=\(x) mean(x,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Then create an imputed version of `y`:

```
df$imputed_y <- ifelse( is.na(df$y) , df$mean_y , df$y )
```